# String-integer convert? Compiler Error Message: CS1502

Tags: ms-access, error-handling

```
localhost.WebService x = new localhost.WebService();סרוויס 

if (Session["UserName"]!= null)
{
    string UserName = Session["UserName "].ToString();
    HiddenField HiddenField1 = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1");
    Image y = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image1");

    int Price = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
    int BuyerID = int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
    x.AddOrder(BuyerID, Price, y.ImageUrl); 
}
else 
    Response.Redirect("Registration.aspx");

[WebMethod]
public void AddOrder(int BuyerID, int Price, int ArtPiece)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter x = new OleDbDataAdapter("AddOrder", objConn);
    x.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    OleDbParameter objParam = new OleDbParameter("@BuyerID", OleDbType.Char);
    objParam.Value = BuyerID;
    x.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(objParam);

    objParam = new OleDbParameter("@Price", OleDbType.Char);
    objParam.Value = Price;
    x.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(objParam);

    objParam = new OleDbParameter("@ArtPiece", OleDbType.Char);
    objParam.Value = ArtPiece;
    x.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(objParam);

    x.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The value `ArtPiece` is string type in the Access file. On this line

```
x.AddOrder(BuyerID, Price, y.ImageUrl);
```

`y.ImageUrl` shows an error. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have declared ArtPiece as *int*:

```
public void AddOrder(int BuyerID, int Price, int ArtPiece)
```

I guess it should be:

```
public void AddOrder(int BuyerID, int Price, string ArtPiece)
```